# Can not set 'fill' attribute to 'inherit' with Snap.SVG

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I want a `circle` in a `g` element to inherit the fill color from the group element.

code:

```
var c = paper.circle(0, 0, 50).attr({fill:'inherit'});
var g = paper.g(c).attr({fill:'#F00'});
console.log(c.attr('fill');
```

output:

```
rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

The `fill` attribute of `c` results in `#000000`. If I manually set the value to `inherit` per HTML inspector in Firefox the color is inherited properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle will automatically inherit the colour of the parent, as long as the attribute or css isn't set on it.

So if you remove the '.attr({fill:'inherit'});' it will actually work.

```
var c = paper.circle(0, 0, 50);
var g = paper.g(c).attr({fill:'#F00'});
console.log(c.attr('fill'));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swy46sr4/)

Comment: It turns out that `none` is an accepted value but `inherit` not.